# Cloudant and Node calls working some of the time

Tags: node.js, cloudant

This may seem a little simple of me but I have a cloudant database and am attempting to get information from each document. So far I have this script written in js
`ciaran.list(function(err, data){
    rows=data.rows
    //console.log(rows)
    for ( row in rows){
        id=rows[row].id;
        ciaran.get(id,function(err, data){
            console.log(data.obj.date)
        } )
    };
})`

All of the 'setup' is ok because it returns some of the data as expected> the issue is when I run it I get a few responses back the undefined for the rest of them or just an error message

> ciarans-mbp:CloudantNode cdarcy$ node cloudantSearch.js
>   2000-02-28
>   2003-08-21
>   2004-03-31
>   2004-02-17
>   2003-12-12
>   2003-12-08
>   2003-09-24
>   2003-12-03
>   2003-12-05
>   2004-07-30
>   /Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/cloudantSearch.js:21
>               console.log(data.obj.date)
>                               ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined
>       at /Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/cloudantSearch.js:21:20
>       at Request._callback (/Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/node_modules/cloudant-nano/lib/nano.js:240:7)
>       at Request.self.callback (/Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (/Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/node_modules/request/request.js:1081:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/cdarcy/Documents/onboarding/CloudantNode/node_modules/request/request.js:1001:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)

I have a funny feeling this has something to do with asynchronous calls but since I'm new to Node can anyone see any other reason why the code code will work for some but not for others?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first call to Cloudant (`ciaran.list`) is returning a list document ids. You are then looping through these and doing a separate GET request to fetch each document's body.

The same thing can be achieved in one API call by adding `include_docs=true` to your first API call e.g.

```
ciaran.list({include_docs: true}, function(err, data) { ...
```

The `data` will now contain a `doc` attribute for each of the `rows` returned which contains the document body.

You are probably running out of Cloudant requests because your "for loop" is running a lot of GET requests in parallel. If you want to control the "parallelism" for your Node code, take a look at the [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library.

Comment: Thanks Glynn That seems to have fixed the issue. Much appreciated, I was afraid that it was going to need callback after callback to rescue this

Answer (score 0):

you may be exceeding the number of API request in a given time period (HTTP status code 429). if that is the case, you can use the retry plugin to retry the connection in the event of an 429 error:

https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#request-plugins

https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#the-retry-plugin